# using insertAdjacentHTML with a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, css-grid

So I'm trying to recreate the Github contribution grid using React.

I'm trying to use insertAdjacentHTML to populate the grid container with a bunch of divs that I can then style.

However, React is throwing me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null"

Here is my simple code:

```
export default function NewHabit() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');

  for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    gridContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id="box></div>`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by just doing it the React way:

```
export default function NewHabit() {
  let grid = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    grid.push(<div className="box"></div>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container">{grid}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the component is not rendered yet when NewHabit starts to execute.
you have to put it after `componentDidMount` or `useEffect(() => {}, [])`, they execute after the component mounts and has been added to the DOM.

besides, it's not safe to do this using `insertAdjacentHTML/Elmenent`. react has a virtual dom that does not keep this type of change in it. after a rerender, it might render what it had in the virtual dom. for example, an empty grid.
it's better to add your boxes in react way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read carefully the [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) part of the React documentation. The important thing you should learn is the fact that React is working using virtual DOM, so you don't have a direct access to the browser's  DOM.

Second, I really discourage you from the direct DOM manipulation. React offers you a number of options to render html dynamically (actually, it renders dynamically all the time). For example, instead of inserting html you may use [lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

```js
export default function NewHabit() {
  let gridElements = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    gridElements.push(<div id="box" key={i}></div>)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container">{gridElements}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if you really want the direct DOM access, just use ref:

```js
import {useRef} from 'react'

export default function NewHabit() {
  const containerRef= useRef(null);

  if (containerRef.current) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
      containerRef.current.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id="box></div>`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container" ref={containerRef}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```